# Авторизация через php curl

Tags: php, curl

Стоит задача с одного домена обратиться к другому домену, передав некоторый массив информации на созданный рест-ресурс.
Делаю при помощи cURL

```
//массив для передачи на другой домен (рест-ресурс)
$images_urls = json_encode($api_response['result']['images']);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.ru/rest/get-client-images-sizes');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
$result = curl_exec($curl);


if($result === FALSE) echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
else echo "it works!";
curl_close($curl);
```

Результат: cURL Error: Failed to connect to mysite.ru port 80: Connection refused

Comment: А этот рест сервер вообще доступен по 80 порту? Похоже, что там фаервол не пускает, независимо от вашего кода

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, что оба этих домена расположены на dev сервере. В hosts прописаны они оба

Comment: в hosts то прописаны, но запущено ли второе приложение и слушает ли оно на 80 порту?

Comment: а если слушает, то что у второго приложения в логах в момент обращения к нему

Comment: загрузил версию сайта на боевой сервер, заработало.